# Random sampling users

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

My dataframe has multiple rows by users, like this:

| User | Value |
| --- | --- |
| A | 12 |
| A | 5 |
| B | 3 |
| C | 7 |
| D | 50 |
| D | 1 |

I wanted to make a sample where i'll get all rows by user. Say that A and C are randomly selected, then i would have:

| User | Value |
| --- | --- |
| A | 12 |
| A | 5 |
| C | 7 |

How to do this in python?

Comment: you can probably sample the user column and then filter by it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can randomly sample unique(s) Users, then use `isin` and boolean indexing:

```
df[df['User'].isin(df['User'].drop_duplicates().sample(n=2))]
```

Or with numpy:

```
df[df['User'].isin(np.random.choice(df['User'].unique(), 2, replace=False))]
```

Example:

```
  User  Value
3    C      7
4    D     50
5    D      1
```

Answer (score 0):

With `.sample()`:

```
df.sample(n=3)
```

| index | User | Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | 5 |
| 0 | A | 12 |
| 4 | D | 50 |

There are many different parameters you can set.
https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sample.html

With `n=` you define how many result you want.

With `replace=True or False`, you allow or disallow sampling of the same row more than once.